# Background taskhost & transfere constantly restarting

Tags: windows-10, rundll32.exe

Saw this in process hacker after I upgraded to Windows 10, it (dllhost.exe) seems to be constantly launching and closing rundll32. BackgroundTaskHost, and backgroundTransfereHost are also starting and stopping (by svchost).

[image]

Is this normal? Or is is something I need to worry about... Thanks!

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/LQ9vM3vf and give e the generated file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here's the zipped file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5QLw0T8QgqdzRFRlcxb0xDaWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/runtime-broker-high-cpu-usage/4302a4dd-44c1-474e-8e6a-3c00889c65a7) at answers.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from the xperf Trace I can see that the BackgroundTaskHost and backgroundTransferHost processes belong to `Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager`. On [twitter I found a comment](https://twitter.com/h0x0d/status/578403594824593411), that this belongs to framework which allows apps to show advertisements/Suggestions.

Seams to be valid, but I can't see why they are called so often and if this is normal. I've removed all that app related things and run a Win10 in a VM which is nearly a Win7 so I can't tell you too many things about all this app things running in Windows 10.